# Как добиться эффекта выезжания блоков друг из друга при загрузке?

Tags: javascript, html, css, меню

Есть блок с меню разделенный на 2 пропорциональные части, которые ракрываются как шторки в обе стороны из единого центра [фидл](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OwLvwb)
Как сделать так, чтобы пункты меню повлялись как будто плавно выезжая друг из друга каждый в свою сторону, т.е. начало движения каждого было за центральной осью

```js
$(function() {
  $('.menu-nav-1').addClass('active');
  $('.menu-nav-2').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.section {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #7b1fa2;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu-block {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu-nav-1 {
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform: scaleX(0) translateX(0%);
  transform-origin: right center;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.menu-nav-1 a {
  color: #fff;
}

.menu-nav-2 {
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform: scaleX(0) translateX(0%);
  transform-origin: left center;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.menu-nav-1.active,
.menu-nav-2.active {
  transform: scaleX(1) translateX(0%);
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">
  <div class="menu-block">
    <div class="menu-nav-1">
      <a href="#">Main</a>
      <a href="#">Porfolio</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-nav-2">
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Contacts</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.section {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #7b1fa2;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu-block {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.menu-section{
  width:50%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.menu-nav{
  padding:0 25px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  white-space:nowrap;
  animation:show .7s ease-in;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
.menu-nav-1 {
  background-color: #000;
  transform:translateX(100%);
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
}

.menu-nav-1 a {
  color: #fff;
}

.menu-nav-2 {
  background-color: #fff;
  transform:translateX(-100%);
  margin:0 auto 0 0;
}
@keyframes show{
  to{
    transform:translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="menu-block">
   <div class="menu-section"> 
    <div class="menu-nav menu-nav-1">
      <a href="#">Main</a>
      <a href="#">Porfolio</a>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="menu-section">
    <div class="menu-nav menu-nav-2">
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Contacts</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```